# How to populate test data from Oracle database to web Application Field

Tags: java, selenium, testng, oracle12c

I am trying to use test data from oracle database and populate test data in the web application using Selenium Webdriver in the Eclipse using Java. I am using Web element/id/xpath/class id from property file.

However, I am getting this error:

```
org.testng.TestNGException: 
Method testFireFox requires 2 parameters but 0 were supplied in the @Test annotation.
    at org.testng.internal.Parameters.checkParameterTypes(Parameters.java:191)
    at org.testng.internal.Parameters.createParameters(Parameters.java:127)
    at org.testng.internal.Parameters.createParameters(Parameters.java:376)
    at org.testng.internal.Parameters.handleParameters(Parameters.java:451)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.handleParameters(Invoker.java:1270)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.createParameters(Invoker.java:985)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:1075)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:125)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:108)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:774)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:624)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:359)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:354)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:312)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:261)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1215)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1140)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1048)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.run(RemoteTestNG.java:112)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:205)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:176)
```

Here is my Base class Code:

```
package com.provider;

import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.util.Properties;
import oracle.net.ns.NetException;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeSuite;


public class BaseClass {

    static WebDriver driver;

     @BeforeSuite
     public void setup() throws InterruptedException, IOException{

         driver=new FirefoxDriver();

         driver.manage().window().maximize();


         Properties obj = new Properties();

         FileInputStream objfile = new FileInputStream(System.getProperty("user.dir") +"\\src\\com\\provider\\Object.Properties");
         obj.load(objfile);

        driver.get(obj.getProperty("URL"));
     }
}
```

Here is my Extended class Code:

```
package com.provider;

import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.util.Properties;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.testng.Assert;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;



public class ProApp extends BaseClass{



@Test
    public void setUpConnection() throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException, FileNotFoundException, InterruptedException, IOException {

         String driver_DBPath = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@Host:Port:SID";
         String DB_username = "*****";
         String DB_password = "*****";
     String Query = "select * from Table";
     Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(driver_DBPath, DB_username, DB_password);
     Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
     ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(Query);


     while(rs.next()){

         String Email = rs.getString("CLAIM_NUMBER");
         String Pwd = rs.getString("INDIVIDUAL_NUM");

         testUserNamePassword(Email, Pwd);
     }

    }

    @Test(priority=1)
    public void clickLoginLink() throws InterruptedException, IOException {

    Properties obj = new Properties();

    FileInputStream objfile = new FileInputStream(System.getProperty("user.dir") +"\\src\\com\\provider\\Object.Properties");
    obj.load(objfile);


    Thread.sleep(1000);
    driver.findElement(By.xpath(obj.getProperty("ClickOnLoginLink"))).click();
    Thread.sleep(1000);

    }

    @Test(priority=2)
    public void testUserNamePassword(String Email1, String Pwd1) throws InterruptedException, IOException {

    Thread.sleep(1000);
    Properties obj = new Properties();

    FileInputStream objfile = new FileInputStream(System.getProperty("user.dir") +"\\src\\com\\provider\\Object.Properties");
    obj.load(objfile);

    Thread.sleep(1000);
    driver.findElement(By.xpath(obj.getProperty("Email"))).clear();
    Thread.sleep(1000);
    driver.findElement(By.xpath(obj.getProperty("Email"))).sendKeys(Email1);
    Thread.sleep(1000);
    driver.findElement(By.xpath(obj.getProperty("Pwd"))).clear();
    Thread.sleep(1000);
    driver.findElement(By.xpath(obj.getProperty("Pwd"))).sendKeys(Pwd1);
    Thread.sleep(1000);
    driver.findElement(By.xpath(obj.getProperty("Submit"))).click();
    Thread.sleep(1000);

    }

    @Test(priority=3)
    public void loginVerify() throws InterruptedException, IOException{

        Properties obj = new Properties();

        FileInputStream objfile = new FileInputStream(System.getProperty("user.dir") +"\\src\\com\\provider\\Object.Properties");
        obj.load(objfile);

        Assert.assertEquals("Wel Come To Testing World!!!", driver.findElement(By.xpath(obj.getProperty("WelComeToTestingWorld"))).getText());

    }    

    @Test(priority=4)
    public void logonVerify() throws InterruptedException, IOException{

        Properties obj = new Properties();

        FileInputStream objfile = new FileInputStream(System.getProperty("user.dir") +"\\src\\com\\provider\\Object.Properties");
        obj.load(objfile);

        WebElement DashboardHeader = driver.findElement(By.xpath(obj.getProperty("WelComeToTestingWorld")));
        DashboardHeader.getText().equals("Wel Come To Testing World!!!");

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, I figure it out that I haven't given Priority where I have provided database connection method information so that when script is running then script is following TestNG framework in order to execute test and script start executing Test(priority=1), Test(priority=2) and so on... And for database connection where I only provided "Test" before starting database connection method. I should have also prioritize database connection method as Test(priority=2). So just prioritize database connection method resolve my issue.

Answer (score 0):

Your `@Test`-enabled `testFireFox()` method seems to want two arguments (`CLAIM_NUMBER`, `INDIVIDUAL_NUMBER`), yet you haven't told TestNG what values it can pass to your method.

In the vast majority of cases, `@Test` methods are no-arg. However, TestNG [does allow arguments to be passed](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#parameters), provided you configure the parameter values properly, e.g.:

```
@Parameters({"first-name"})
@Test
public void testSingleString(String firstName) {
  System.out.println("Invoked testString " + firstName);
  assert "Cedric".equals(firstName);
}
```

There isn't really enough detail in your question to explain how your two dependencies can be fulfilled, but do read the linked documentation on Data Providers in case that's the answer.

Comment: hi Andrew - I provided parameter for TestNG. However, automated cursor is going through email address field and password field but not populating database data in these fields.

Comment: Could you clarify your question to explain how you expect this to work? I answered your specific question about the error already, but you didn't say anything about how those properties should be actually populated from the DB, e.g. which fields from the table.

Comment: I am trying to figure it out about how I can get CLAIM_NUMBER column and INDIVIDUAL_NUM column value from database and populate them in the Email Address field and Password field respective of the web application page. My Web Driver cursor is able to locate Email address field and Password field but the mapping that bring database data and populate those data into web field are seem not working out here.

Comment: And, I stored web element for example - xpath, class id in the property file and Property file I placed under src folder in the Project folder. Web element - xpath, class id locate Email address field and Password field in the web application. Above code is popualting "Eamil" and Pwd" text in the Email Address field and password field rather than CLAIM_NUMBER column and INDIVIDUAL_NUM column value from the database.